How can i use vue with .vue file
Vue is simply manipulate html with javascript.In basic you create a vue object and You mount that object on a div with an id.I wanted to test that i create a .vue file and import this .vue file to a js file and mount it on a div. But it fails. This project is just for trying. This is my project schema. 
App.vue content :
<template>
<h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
<h1>.Vue file</h1>
</template>
<script>
export default{
    name: 'App',
    data(){
        return{
            msg: 'VUE JS 3'
        }
    }
}
</script>

app.js content :
import App from './App.vue';
const app = Vue.createApp(App);

app.mount('#app');

index.html content :
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Vue Basics</title>
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Jost:wght@400;700&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.4.9/dist/vue.global.js" defer></script> 
    <script src="app.js" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
  </body>
</html>

In chrome console output is 
when i add type="module" to script tag of app.js output is :

when i change type="module" to type="application/octet-stream", there is no error in console but nothing on web page.
I think i can not import a .vue file or .vue file is not working when i import it but why?

Do you have a running HTTP server?

I'd suggest reading the Quick Start Guide. It seems like you're mixing the Creating a Vue App with Using Vue from CDN. Both work but are different ways of using the framework.

I already read this guide but my question is not this. Maybe i couldn't explain myself clear. Still thank you.The question is why i can't import a .vue file to .js file. I answered my own question but i can't comment it here because explanation for too long for a comment. You can read it from answers.

You can simulate this by specifying a <template> that contains the HTML of the App component. and inject it into the #app DOM element.


// Grab the template HTML content, and insert it into the #app div's HTML
const app = document.querySelector('#app').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',
  document.querySelector('[data-id="App"]').innerHTML);

/** App.js */
const { ref } = Vue;
const App = {
  setup() {
    const msg = ref('VUE JS 3');
    return { msg };
  }
}

// Mount the App on the #app div in the DOM
Vue.createApp(App).mount('#app');
<!-- App.vue -->
<template data-id="App">
  <p>{{msg}}</p>
  <input v-model="msg">
</template>
<div id="app"></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.4.21/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>



Here is an alternative approach, that keeps the App.vue component in-tact.


/* App.vue */
const AppComponent = `
<template>
  <p>{{msg}}</p>
  <input v-model="msg">
</template>
<script>
const { ref } = Vue;
export default {
  setup() {
    const msg = ref('VUE JS 3');
    return { msg };
  }
}
<\/script>
`;

// Grab the template HTML content, and insert it into the #app div's HTML
const mountPoint = document.querySelector('#app');
const app = new DOMParser().parseFromString(AppComponent, 'text/html');
const appTemplate = app.querySelector('template').innerHTML;

mountPoint.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', appTemplate);

let appScript = app.querySelector('script').innerHTML;
appScript = appScript.replace('export default', 'const App =');
appScript += `\nVue.createApp(App).mount('#app')`;

const script = document.createElement('script');
script.textContent = appScript;
document.head.append(script);
<div id="app"></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.4.21/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>




Thank you for your answer but i didn't ask this. I asked  why i can't import a .vue file to .js file with using vue from cdn. I found out the answer. And i wrote it below.

I already read these but my question is not this. When you use createApp function of Vue package, you are giving a vue element as an argument for this function. I was trying to create .vue file and import it to a .js file, this will be also a Vue element. Theoretically this should work too beacuse createApp function just want a vue element as a parameter.
I've been researching this for a while and this is what I found out: It is not about vue, it is about webpack or project development tools. You need import .vue file as a module but if project has not a webpack or something like this tool, you can not import it as a module. When we use Vue from CDN, we are just integrate vue but we don't install any webpack so project can not handle .vue file and can not import a .vue file to .js file. If we want to import a .vue file to a .js file we should use webpack or vue cli or some tools like these.These tools allow you to handle .vue files properly and integrate them into your project. Vue CLI or webpack enables you to import .vue files into your .js files, thus allowing you to define Vue components in separate .vue files and then use them in your .js files. I hope i could explain my answer clear.

A MIME type issue is usually a lack of dev server. Could be Vite, Webpack or just a simple HTTP one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve

Yeah this is about this. When we use this tools we can import .vue to .js files.

And this is how it is supposed to work: you cannot have a running app without a server, even the smallest one for an SSG app. For SSR, you need a fully working Node one too, which is also not free.

I hope I understand your question correctly,
Take a look at the following link:
https://github.com/FranckFreiburger/vue3-sfc-loader
It provides the option to use Vue's single-file components without JavaScript modules. I use it for my projects.
